# How to pass variables in URL and page?

Tags: php

My code in index.php:

```
<?php

$keyword = ($_GET['keyword']);
$adid = $_GET['adid'];

header("Location: http://www.tracking.com/base.php?asdf&keyword=&ad=" .$keyword .$adid);

?>
```

The tracking link is supposed to end with:

```
&keyword={keyword}&ad={AdId}
```

I need to pass the keyword and AdId through the URL onto the landing page which then redirects and pass both variables to the tracking link.

This is the URL I was trying:

```
www.example.com/?keyword={keyword}&ad={AdId}
```

I don't think I can test if my format above is correct unless I run search traffic to it.

I need help on getting the codes right and getting the URL to pass them correctly.

Edit: Did I format the URL to pass the variables correctly?

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
header("Location: http://www.tracking.com/base.php?asdf&keyword=&ad=" .$keyword .$adid);
```

to

```
header("Location: http://www.tracking.com/base.php?keyword=$keyword&ad=$adid");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header("Location:",'http://www.example.com/?&keyword='.$keyword.'&ad='.$adid);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<?php

$keyword = ($_GET['keyword']);
$adid = $_GET['adid'];

header("Location: http://www.tracking.com/base.php?keyword=$keyword&ad=$adid");

?>
```

Comment: Hi, Try put a little description about the differences between your code and the code of question

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 header("Location: http://www.tracing.com/base.php?asdf&keyword=$keyword&ad=$aid");
```

It seems that I post later,Ah.